# asp update panel and asp gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have an update panel and a gridview inside of the panel. The gridview has an onRowCommand attached. On the row commands the page is doing a full posting back. It is a fairly large gridview in terms of columns. Has anyone had any problems or issues around gridviews that are similar to this?

Thanks very much

Comment: couldn't IsPostback on your page_load solve your problem

Comment: You should show us the GridView(at least the declaration) and the codebehind(at least the `onRowCommand`). You should also clarify what actually your problem is. *"On the row commands the page is doing a full posting back"*. Does that mean you want an asynchronous postback and that is your problem? Please be more carefully on wording and formatting your questions, because you want other people to spent their time to help you.

Comment: OkayGuy what would i put in the isPostBack. Yeah Tim i want an asynch post back. If a user has hundreds of entries in the gridview I don't want them to be put back to the top of the page after a postback.

Comment: Well you bind your data to the gridview in `if(!IsPostBack){//here}`.

Comment: "On the row commands the page is doing a full posting back" - partial postback surely? 

Ideally you should bind your data once like OkayGuy posted above, then MyGridView_RowCommand should modify the data and then if necessary, rebind the gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, putting yourgridview.databind() in the following if statement will help you stop repopulation of your what ever databound controls. Use this always if want you want the controls populated at the first load of the page only. Or please elaborate your question more

**if Not IsPostBack then

  ' bind your controls here

End if**